# TTree objects; using Draw options to histogram the difference

Tags: c++, data-analysis, root-framework

This macro works with [ROOT (cern)](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/) [TTree](https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TTree.html#TTree:Draw) objects. Its aim is to display one histogram with another subtracted from it. The trees are friends. I am attempting to use the `Draw()` options to subtract one histogram from another;

```
tree1->Draw("hit_PMTid - plain.hit_PMTid");
```

However its making the wrong axis negative. The result looks like;

[image: oddly symmetrical graph]

As I know the graphs have almost the same shape this is clearly a display of them back to back. How can I get it to change the axis on which it subtracts, from x to y?

Its probably not needed but here is the full macro;

```
void testReader3(){
  TFile * file1 = TFile::Open("alt4aMaskOutput.root");
  TTree * tree1 = (TTree*)file1->Get("HitsTree");
  tree1->AddFriend("plain = HitsTree", "plainMaskOutput.root");

  tree1->Draw("hit_PMTid - plain.hit_PMTid");
}
```

Comment: Rene's answer here [https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=10363] is probably what's needed but I cant find the documentation that explains how to use it.

Comment: For anyone else trying to do this it seems to be easier to re bin the histograms and then use Add()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you gave will make a histogram of the difference between the `hit_PMTid` and `plain.hit_PMTid` variables for every event of the tree. If instead you want to look at the bin by bin differences in the distributions, you need to fill two histograms, then subtract them (used `TH1::Add`). As you say, you have to force the same binning. An example of this would be:

```
void testReader3(){
  TFile * file1 = TFile::Open("alt4aMaskOutput.root");
  TTree * tree1 = (TTree*)file1->Get("HitsTree");
  tree1->AddFriend("plain = HitsTree", "plainMaskOutput.root");

  // Draw the two histograms from the tree, specifying the
  // output histogram name and binning
  tree1->Draw("hit_PMTid>>hist1(100,0,6000)");
  tree1->Draw("plain.hit_PMTid>>hist2(100,0,6000)");

  // Retrieve the two histograms we just created
  TH1* hist1 = gDirectory->Get("hist1");
  TH1* hist2 = gDirectory->Get("hist2");

  // Subtract
  TH1* hist_diff = (TH1*) hist1->Clone("hist_diff");
  hist_diff->Add(hist2, -1);

}
```